# How to get the right route in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I'm learning node js and I get this error when I'm trying to get my data or add something the router doesn't work and I'm lost I don't see where the problem is.
in my cmder, there is no problem it says connection to the server, and the DB is successful.
**this is my connectDB file:**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose') 
    const URI = process.env.DATABASE;
    mongoose.connect(URI, { useUnifiedTopology: true } )
    .then(()=>console.log("connect"))
    .catch((error)=> console.log(error)) ;
```

**and this is my index.js file:**

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 3000
    require("dotenv").config({path:".env"})
    const bodyParser=require("body-parser")
    const products = require('./Routes/products')
    //connect to the database
    require("./ConnectDB");
    
    
    //middleware
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    
    //routes
    app.use('/products',products);
    
    //server
    app.listen(port,() => {
        console.log(`listen to http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
```

**This is my controller:**

```
    const Product=require('../Models/Product')
    
    exports.getProducts=async(req,res)=>{
    try{ 
        console.log("requete",req.body)
        const products=await Product.find()
        res.send(products)
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
    }
    
    
    exports.addProduct=async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            console.log("requete",req.body)
            const product= await new Product(req.body).save()
            res.send(product)
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    
    exports.updateProduct=async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            const product=await Product.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.productId},{ $set: req.body },
                { new: true })
            res.send(product)
        }
        catch{
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    exports.deleteProduct=async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            const product=await Product.findOneAndRemove({_id:req.params.productId})
            res.send(product)
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

**and this is my routes file:**

```
    const express =require('express')
    const router= express.Router()
    const {getProducts,addProduct,updateProduct,deleteProduct}=require('../Controllers/product')
    
    router.get("/",getProducts)
    router.post("/new",addProduct)
    router.put("/:productId",updateProduct)
    router.delete("/:productId",deleteProduct)
    
    module.exports = router
```

**and this is my model:**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
         name:{
             type:String,
             required: true
         } 
        });
    const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
    module.exports=Product
```

when I enter **http://localhost:3000/** I get this error " **cannot GET /** "
or when I enter **http://localhost:3000/?name=test** I get the same problem with **POST**.
if anyone knows what I did wrong I appreciate it thank you in advance.
**this is my project structure :**
[image]

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo Please ?

Comment: i don't have it online. if you want to check something tell me I'll show you.

Comment: Ok.So please provide all Your code and file&folder structure ;-)

Comment: Where do you use this router file?

Comment: okay i added everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mounted your router under `/products`. So your requests should contain `products` as their base-url , e.g:

```
 http://localhost:3000/products
```

Comment: oh my god! i've been going crazy and i completely forgot about it!